# WSO2 ESB (4.8.1) 101507 Error

Tags: web-services, wso2, sslv3, wso2-esb

I have a very simple API at WSO2 ESB like this:

```
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/query">
  <inSequence>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
     <property name="ContentType" value="application/json; charset=utf-8" scope="axis2"></property>

     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">

        <format>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
              <soap:Body>
                <Query xmlns="http://testws.example.com/">
                  <foo>$1</foo>
                </Query>
              </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
        </format>

        <args>
           <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.foo"></arg>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
     <header name="Action" value="http://testws.example.com/query"></header>

     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="https://testws.example.com/query.asmx" format="soap11"></address>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
```

I changed some information. My endpoint is a .NET based web service. When I use this query service, 101507 error occurs and endpoint is cancelled. I really have not idea what to do this problem. Some additional information:

- Endpoint supports SSLV3, but It also supports TLS1.
- WSO2 also supports SSLV3
- When I try SoapUI, Java or C# clients; this query web service works like a charm!
- Although the certificate is shown as secured in browsers. I had to add the endpoint address certificate to WSO2 keystore. Because WSO2 did not accept the certificate as "secure"

What should I do? Is there anything? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you get any ssl related exception in esb/backend ?

Comment: No, nothing. Logs print only endpoint suspend message

Comment: esb also in local machine where soap ui and other exists.? if not just check whether you could reach to the endpoint using curl from the machine where esb is isntalled

Comment: Yes. Soapui and others are in the same computer with esb. I can reach service endpoint with curl and browser in the esb os.

Comment: Can you enable wirelog and invoke the api and add the wirelog to the question . it could provide any clue to troubleshoot
http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Comment: Unfortunately I could not managed it. I had to upgrade to the WSO ESB 5.0.0 to overcome this problem. Thanks you @Jenananthan